# How to move one view when other is dragging

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I'm trying to move one view by dragging another using Auto Layout. My scene looks like this:

[image: Scene with upper view which is desired to be dragged by touch and the view below which should follow the view above]

This turquoise view is a view which I want to drag by touching it and the red one below is a view which should follow the view which I'm dragging. I added constraint between these views which is Vertical Spacing constraint with constant equal 0.

I added timer which moves upper smaller view one pixel per second but unfortunately the red one is still in the same place.

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSTimer *_timer;
}

- (IBAction)onDragButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    _timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(_onDrag) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


- (void)_onDrag {
    self.draggable.center = CGPointMake(self.draggable.center.x, self.draggable.center.y - 1);
    [self.dragged setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

I've also tried with custom made constraint like this:

```
NSLayoutConstraint *constraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:self.dragged attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.draggable attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0];
[self.view addConstraint:constraint];
```

But without any positive results.

What should I do to implement this behaviour correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What other constraints does the turquoise view have?

Comment: I selected that view so you can see all constraints for this view. It has horizontally centered constraint and also width and height. Bottom red view has constraint bottom to superview which has priority 250. Without this constraint this is also not working. Red has also width, height and leading and trailing set to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use AutoLayout you lose your frames and centers. Instead you rely on the constant value of `NSLayoutConstraints`. So your code that needs to change is here:

```
- (void)_onDrag {
    self.draggable.center = CGPointMake(self.draggable.center.x, self.draggable.center.y - 1);
    [self.dragged setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

make it something more like

```
- (void)_onDrag:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)gesture {
    self.draggableConstraint.constant = [gesture locationInView:self.view].y;
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
}
```

Note the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. Instead of a button, you should consider a simple view with a gesture recognizer designed for moving views. Then your `OnDrag:` method can ask the gesture where the touch is and update your `self.draggableConstraint` accordingly. You may need to do some adjustments such as `constant = (GESTURE LOCATION Y) - (DRAGGABLE STARTING Y);` to handle the offset. The magic sauce here is that you hold on to a constraint and then change its constant before calling `-[UIView layoutIfNeeded]` which triggers an immediate recalculation of all constraints.'

Comment: Anytime. Happy Coding :)